# Failed to lookup view "..." in views directory "..."

Tags: node.js, pug

today a weird error appeared. I'm getting an error with res.render, but I used it pretty often and I kinda know how to use it.

contact.js:

```
router.post('/', function (req, res, next) {

    if (!validator.isEmail(req.body.email)) {
        req.flash('error', '...');
        return res.render('contact', {
            message: req.flash()
        })
    }

    contactmessages.create({
        firstname: req.body.firstname,
        lastname: req.body.lastname,
        email: req.body.email,
        message: req.body.message,
        subject: req.body.subject
    }).then(res.render('responseviews/dafaultInfoLayout', {
            user: req.user,
            info: '...'
    })).catch(function (err) {
        res.render('responseviews/noResponseDB');
    });
});
```

contact.jade:

```
extends layout

block content
    ul.breadcrumb
        each breadcrumb in breadcrumbs
            li: a(href="#{breadcrumb.url}") #{breadcrumb.name}
    if(message)
        span.label.label-danger #{message.error}
    .container
        .row
            .col-md-12
                form.form-horizontal(method='post').col-md-10
                    fieldset
                        legend.text-center.header Kontaktformular
                        .form-group
                            span.col-md-1.col-md-offset-2.text-center
                                i.fa.fa-user.bigicon
                            .col-md-8
                                if(user)
                                    input#fname.form-control(name='firstname', type='text', value=user.firstname)
                                else
                                    input#fname.form-control(name='firstname', type='text', placeholder='Vorname')
                        .form-group
                            span.col-md-1.col-md-offset-2.text-center
                                i.fa.fa-user.bigicon
                            .col-md-8
                                if(user)
                                    input#lname.form-control(name='lastname', type='text', value=user.lastname)
                                else
                                    input#lname.form-control(name='lastname', type='text', placeholder='Nachname')
                        .form-group
                            span.col-md-1.col-md-offset-2.text-center
                                i.fa.fa-envelope-o.bigicon
                            .col-md-8
                                if(user)
                                    input#email.form-control(name='email', type='text', value=user.email)
                                else
                                    input#email.form-control(name='email', type='text', placeholder='Email Adresse')
                        .form-group
                            span.col-md-1.col-md-offset-2.text-center
                                i.fa.fa-envelope-o.bigicon
                            .col-md-8
                                input#email.form-control(name='subject', type='text', placeholder='Betreff')
                        .form-group
                            span.col-md-1.col-md-offset-2.text-center
                                i.fa.fa-pencil-square-o.bigicon
                            .col-md-8
                                textarea#message.form-control(name='message', placeholder='Schreibe hier, was du ' +
                                'uns mitteilen oder fragen willst', rows='7')
                        .form-group
                            .col-md-12
                                button.btn.btn-primary.btn-lg.col-md-offset-6(type='submit') Absenden
```

responseviews/defaultInfoLayout.jade:

```
extends ../layout

block content
    h1 #{info}
```

Error I got:

> ```
> Error: Failed to lookup view "responseviews/dafaultInfoLayout" in views directory "/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/app/views"
>     at EventEmitter.render (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:579:17)
>     at ServerResponse.render (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:961:7)
>     at /home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/app/routes/contact.js:30:14
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>     at next (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:13)
>     at Route.dispatch (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>     at /home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:277:22
>     at Function.process_params (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
>     at next (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:271:10)
>     at Function.handle (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:176:3)
>     at router (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:46:12)
>     at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
>     at trim_prefix (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:312:13)
>     at /home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:280:7
>     at Function.process_params (/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:330:12)
> ```

This is what my files look like:

[image]

Comment: did you specify `app.engine` and `app.set('view engine', 'jade');`?

Comment: @Muco So does file `/home/muecahit/Schreibtisch/ltebjade/lteb/app/views/response/dafaultInfo.jade` actually exists on your harddrive? In contact.js i would expect to see `res.render('response/dafaultInfo'...` since that is the view that view engine failed to lookup. Or is `response/dafaultInfo` included in another view?

Comment: @Louy 
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.set('layout', 'layout');

Comment: @Molda yes it exists , i just edited the error message. Now it's correct. Actually the path `responseviews/defaultInfoLayout` is right.

Comment: Note that you have another typo. `then(res.render...)` make no sense. Make it like this: `then(function(user) {res.render...});` Otherwise you won't send the error response correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message says "dafaultInfoLayout", you say "defaultInfoLayout" exists. Is this not just a typo / spelling mistake on your side?

(can't comment due to low rep)

In fact, after reading your code you did indeed spell it incorrectly.

In your contact.js

```
then(res.render('responseviews/dafaultInfoLayout'...
```

Needs to be

```
then(res.render('responseviews/defaultInfoLayout'...
```

That should fix your problem.

Comment: wow this is so embarrassing. I lost so much time trying to solve the problem -.- Should i delete this question? I think its useless now

Comment: If you delete it I lose my first rep, but at the same time it doesn't offer anyone any help.